# Go change from interface to required type

Tags: go, types, type-assertion

I have this method where I receive an `int64` param. The parameter is used in some areas and then is supposed to be passed down to another method (from an external lib) that expects a different type: `type AcctInterimInterval uint32`

I tried converting it to a `uint32` but the script complains about it: `invalid type assertion: ... (non-interface type int on left)`.

I also tried converting it to `AcctInterimInterval` but this time with a different error: `interface conversion: interface {} is int, not main.AcctInterimInterval`

Here's my test code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//  defined in some other lib
type AcctInterimInterval uint32

//  defined in some other lib
func test(value AcctInterimInterval){
    fmt.Println(value)
}

func main() {
    //  int received externally
    interval := 60

    var acctInterval interface{} = interval

    test(acctInterval.(AcctInterimInterval))
}
```

Associated playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tTW5J2FIAy3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `acctInterval` variable wraps an `int` value, so you can only [type-assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) an `int` from it:

```
acctInterval.(int)
```

Which then you can [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to `AcctInterimInterval`:

```
test(AcctInterimInterval(acctInterval.(int)))
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/24xpo6-FCDa).